# formatting a stickman shape in a string. ( want the line feed inside the string to not affect my other code )

Tags: c#, formatting

I have this string that prints a stick man, it uses line feeds, and spaces.
I want a way to print the stick man without the line feeds interfering with my other code
(I want them inside the string at all times )

I'm printing a for loop which shows a stick man going down the stairs.
the stairs part is done. the line feed from my stick man string keeps ruining the stairs.

(my stick man for ref)

```cs
string stick Man ="*****"+"  O\n"+$@"     / | \"+"\n"+$@"     /   \"+"*****";
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [raw string literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/raw-string) you can write something like:

```cs
string stickMan = """
    *****  O
         / | \
         /   \*****
    """;
```

Note that the first and last line with the `"""` are not part of the string and the white spaces to the left (indicated by the position of the terminating `"""`) are also not part of the string.

You cannot have a white space inside a variable name. `string stick Man = ...` will not compile, `string stickMan = ...` will.

I do not understand what you mean by *"want the line feed inside the string to not affect my other code"*. Why should a line feed in a string affect other code?

Another possibility is to use a verbatim string, but unlike the raw string, we must align it to the left, i.e., all white spaces to the left are significant.

```cs
string stickMan = @"*****  O
     / | \
     /   \*****";
```

---

To make an animation, you must control the position of where you print things on the console. for this, you can set the `Console.CursorTop` and `Console.CursorLeft` positions. It is also necessary to to control the position of every line the stick man is made of. This is achieved by storing the stick man lines into an array.

Example:

```cs
const string Step = "****";
const int TopLine = 4, StepHeight = 2;

Console.Write("Number of steps: ");
string stepsText = Console.ReadLine();
int stepsNumber = Int32.Parse(stepsText);

string[] stickMan = new string[]{
    @" O",
    @"/|\",
    @"/ \"
};

// Draw stairs
for (int i = 0; i < stepsNumber; i++) {
    Console.CursorTop = TopLine + StepHeight * i;
    Console.CursorLeft = Step.Length * i;
    Console.Write(Step);
}

// Animate stick man
Console.CursorVisible = false;
for (int i = 0; i < stepsNumber; i++) {
    // Draw stick man
    for (int j = 0; j < stickMan.Length; j++) {
        Console.CursorTop = TopLine + StepHeight * i - stickMan.Length + j;
        Console.CursorLeft = Step.Length * i + 1;
        Console.Write(stickMan[j]);
    }

    // Wait
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);

    // Delete stick man
    for (int j = 0; j < stickMan.Length; j++) {
        Console.CursorTop = TopLine + StepHeight * i - stickMan.Length + j;
        Console.CursorLeft = Step.Length * i + 1;
        Console.Write("    ");
    }
}
Console.CursorVisible = true;
```

Comment: including the whole code might give a better idea ..
//string stepsAmount = Console.ReadLine();
string stickMan ="*****"+"  O\n"+$@"     / | \"+"\n"+$@"     /   \"+"*****";
string space = "    ";
int counter=0;
//int stepsNumber = Int32.Parse(stepsAmount);


Console.Write(stickMan);


for(int i = 0; i < stepsNumber; i++)
{
counter++;

    for(i = 0; i < counter; i++)
    {
        Console.Write(space);
    }

Console.WriteLine("H");
}


so i get the steps increasing in number .. but the stickman string will reset the steps with the line feed inside it